# F# reading custom configuration and representing it as ConfigurationSection with ConfigurationElements

Tags: f#

I am rather new to F# but I have a question about creating and reading custom configuration file. I know how it would look in c# so for example I have a simple config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="customSection" type="Tool.Lib.Config, Tool.Lib" />
  </configSections>

  <communicationSection>
    <responseTimeoutInMs value="900000" />
  </communicationSection>

</configuration>
```

Basing on that in c# it is simple. I am creating model named Config with properties marked as ConfigurationProperty (witch relates to xml node name, in this case responseTimeoutInMs) something like:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("responseTimeoutInMs")]
public ResponseTimeoutConfigElement ResponseTimeoutInMs
{
   get => (ResponseTimeoutConfigElement)base["responseTimeoutInMs"];
   set => base["responseTimeoutInMs"] = value;
}
```

And of course value is set as ConfigurationElement so:

```
public class ResponseTimeoutConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true, DefaultValue = 0)]
    public int Value => (int)base["value"];
}
```

It is a nice mechanism, I can pin converters into it and create types I need while reading configuration.

I know i can read default config using ConfigurationManager and exe configuration map, but this is basic config reading using key and value.

So my question is, is there something similar in F# to this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's quite what you're after as you mention using a "custom configuration file", but in the past I've used the [AppSettings Type Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html) to get strongly typed access to app variables.

If that's not appropriate, there's also a more standard [XML type provider](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) that might help?

I find type providers really useful in avoiding having to write boilerplate code for simple access, and they're a really nice feature of F# development.

Comment: Aye type providers are all i need :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do pretty much the same thing in F# as in C#:

```
type ResponseTimeoutConfigElement() =
    inherit ConfigurationElement()

    [<ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true, DefaultValue = 0)>]
    member this.Value = base.["value"] :?> int

type Config() =
    inherit ConfigurationSection()

    [<ConfigurationProperty("responseTimeoutInMs")>]
    member this.ResponseTimeInMs
        with get() = base.["responseTimeoutInMs"] :?> ResponseTimeoutConfigElement
        and set (value: ResponseTimeoutConfigElement) = base.["responseTimeoutInMs"] <- value
```